# Bayesian calibration for ode system

Tags: ode, bayesian, pymc3, calibration

I tried to use the 'pymc3' package in Python to calibrate a first-order ODE system in a Bayesian way.
I started with a toy ODE system first. It is dy1/dt = y2; dy2/dt = -b* y2 - c*sin(y1). b and c are the parameters I want to calibrate.
Firstly, I generated some outputs for y1 and y2 from t[0,10] by setting parameters b = 0.25 and c = 0.5 with normally distributed noise~N(0,0.7^2). Then, I calibrated the ODE system by setting prior distributions for b~N(0,1) and c~N(0,9) and sigma~HalfNormal
But it gave the errors: (1) TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'TensorVariable'(2)ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.integrate import ode
import pymc3 as pm

def pend(y, t, b, c):
    theta, omega = y
    dydt = [omega, -b*omega - c*np.sin(theta)]
    return dydt

true_b = 0.25
true_c = 5.0

y0 = [np.pi - 0.1, 0.0]
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
sol = odeint(pend, y0, t, args=(true_b, true_c))

true_sigma = 0.7    
noise = np.random.randn(101,2)*true_sigma
Y_obs = sol+noise

pend_model = pm.Model()

with pend_model:

    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    b = pm.Normal('b', mu=0, sd=1)
    c = pm.Normal('c', mu=7, sd=3)
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', sd=1)

    # Expected value of outcome
    mu = odeint(pend, y0, t, args=(b, c))

    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    Y = pm.Normal('Y_obs', mu=mu, sd=sigma, observed=Y_obs)

    trace = pm.sample(draws=5000, tune=500, chains=1)
```

Comment: I found a tutorial on how to use Turing (a probabilistic programming system written entirely in Julia) to bayesian calibrate ODE system. https://turing.ml/dev/tutorials/10-bayesian-differential-equations/. From its explanation, "Previously, functions in Turing and DifferentialEquations were not inter-composable, so Bayesian inference of differential equations needed to be handled by another package called DiffEqBayes.jl ". I believe there is also a need to connect "pymc3" with "odeint". However, I couldn't find a suitable tool online.

Comment: Pymc has a tutorial for ODE integration (in both senses of the word!) over at https://www.pymc.io/projects/examples/en/latest/ode_models/ODE_API_introduction.html . It might come in handy!